# Where does VSCode store the list of open workspaces?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I close and re-open VSCode, it remembers what workspaces I had open. Where does that information live?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It's stored [under the base paths listed here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations), but the data is internal and how/where it is stored will change without notice, i.e. don't mess around with it)

Comment: Thanks @MattBierner I'm asking in the context of e.g. the "**Code Settings Sync**" extension. When syncing between `VSCode` and `VSCode Insiders`, I'd love to be able to switch between them easily as needed with the same workspaces open. At the moment I don't think the extension does that, so I'm simply curious to know why and where that info lives.